# Unable to parse href using beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the following webpage to get a specific href using BS4. They've just changed the page layout and due to that I am unable to parse it correctly. Hope anyone can help.

Webpage trying to scrape: https://www.temit.co.uk/investor/resources/temit-literature
Tag trying to get: href="https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/c667rc7chx/173-fact-sheet-retail-investor-factsheet"

Currently I am using the following code (BS4), however, I am unable to get the specific element anymore.

```
url = "https://www.temit.co.uk/investor/resources/temit-literature"
page = requests.get(url) # Requests website
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'row ng-star-inserted'})
url_TEM = table[1].find_all('a')[0].get('href')
url_TEM = 'https://www.temit.co.uk' + url_TEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is dynamic that's why I use selenium with bs4 and getting the desired output as follows:

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.temit.co.uk/investor/resources/temit-literature"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(8)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table_urls = soup.select('table.table-striped tbody tr td a')
for table_url in table_urls:
    url = table_url['href']
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/gd2tmrc8cl/final-temit-annual-report-31-march-2021
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/lzrcnmhpvr/temit-semi-annual-report-temit-semi-annual-report-30-09-2020
https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/TEM/templeton-emerging-markets-investment-trust-plc/analysis
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/c667rc7chx/173-fact-sheet-retail-investor-factsheethttps://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/bdxrtlljxg/temit_manager_update
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/6djgk6xknx/temit-holdings-report
/content-kid/kid/en-GB/KID-GB0008829292-GB-en-GB.pdf
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/flblzqxmcg/temit-investor-disclosure-document.pdf-26-04-2021
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/l5gmdbf6vp/agm-results-announcement
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/qmkphz9s5s/agm-shareholder-documentation
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/b258tgpjb7/agm-uk-voting-guide
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/c5zhbbnxql/agm-nz-voting-guide
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/shmljbvtjq/temit-annual-report-mar-2019
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/shmljbvtjq/temit-annual-report-mar-2019
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/5bjq2qkmh5/temit-annual-report-mar-2018
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/bnx9mfwlzw/temit-annual-report-mar-2017
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/rfqc7xrnfn/temit-annual-report-mar-2016
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/zfzxlflxnq/temit-annual-report-mar-2015
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/dj9zl8rpcm/temit-annual-report-mar-2014
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/7xshxmkpnh/temit-annual-report-mar-2013
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/7gwx2qmcdr/temit-annual-report-mar-2012
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/drpd7gbvxl/temit-annual-report-mar-2011
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/2pb2kxkgbl/temit-annual-report-mar-2010
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/g6pdr9hq2d/temit-annual-report-mar-2009
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/7pvjf6fhl9/temit-annual-report-mar-2008
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/lzrcnmhpvr/temit-semi-annual-report-temit-semi-annual-report-30-09-2020
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/xwvrncvkj2/temit-half-year-report-sept-2019        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/lbp5ssv8mc/temit-half-year-report-sept-2018        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/hltddqhqcf/temit-half-year-report-sept-2017        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/2tlqxxflgn/temit-half-year-report-sept-2016        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/lbcgztjjkj/temit-half-year-report-sept-2015        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/2tjxzgbdvx/temit-half-year-report-sept-2014        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/gzrpjwb7bf/temit-half-year-report-sept-2013        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/lxhbdrmc8z/temit-half-year-report-sept-2012        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/zzpxrrrpmc/temit-half-year-report-sept-2011        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/zjdd2gn5jc/temit-half-year-report-sept-2010        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/7sbqfxxkrd/temit-half-year-report-sept-2009        
https://franklintempletonprod.widen.net/s/pvswpqkdvb/temit-half-year-report-sept-2008-1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I'll use selenium instead.